# Cloud IDE for local server

Tags: ide, cloud, syntax-highlighting, cloud9-ide

Sorry about the confusing title.

Are there any web IDEs available that can be downloaded and installed on a local server.

For example something like cloud9 or shiftedit but that I can use locally.

I am aware of the ACE text editor which seems to be what a lot of this stuff is based off of but it doesn't seem to do syntax highlighting for mixed html/php/javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you use cloud9 locally? https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9

Answer (score 0):

also, goorm IDE can be alternative~

http://github.com/xenoz0718/goorm/

or npm install goorm -g